# How to create an api service with axios in VueJs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

Im trying to create an api service using this sintax

apiservice.js

```
import axios from 'axios'
import * as users from '@/plugins/apiservice/modules/users';

const apiservice = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.VUE_APP_URL,
  withCredentials: false,
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('sessionToken')}`
  },
})
export default {apiservice, users};
```

users.js

```
import apiservice from "@/plugins/apiservice";

  const login = async (params) => {
    try {
      const result = await apiservice.post('/login', params);
      return result.data;
    } catch (error) {
      return error;
    }
  }
 
  export {login};
```

Component.vue

```
import apiservice from '@/plugins/apiservice';
const response = await apiservice.users.login(this.loginData);
```

I got this error when i enter data **TypeError: *plugins_apiservice__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2*_.default.post is not a function**

**NOTE 1: I tried a GET request to test the connection and i got 200 response**

**NOTE 2: If a use the exact login function inside apiservice, it works perfectly**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apiservice.js` exports the `axios` instance as a subproperty of the default export (i.e., `"apiservice"`):

```js
// apiservice.js
const apiservice = axios.create(/*...*/)
                   
export default {apiservice, users};
```

To use the `axios` instance, you'll have to reference that subproperty:

```js
// users.js
import apiservice from "@/plugins/apiservice";
//...
const result = await apiservice.apiservice.post('/login', params);
```

Alternatively, you could use a *named export*:

```js
// apiservice.js
export const axiosInstance = axios.create(/*...*/)
```

```js
// users.js
import { axiosInstance } from "@/plugins/apiservice";
//...
const result = await axiosInstance.post('/login', params);
```